# Making custom layout that should fullfit the spinner

Tags: android, view, constraints, spinner

My spinner is constrained to guidelines and changes it size depending on the screen size. And then it comes my problem. I have this 
[image: spinner_layout]

its custom_spinner.XML
Its width and height is match constraint
My CustomAdapter

```
     public class MyCustomSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MySpinnerData> 
{
    private Context context;
    private List<MySpinnerData> spinnerData;
    private boolean Car = false;
    private String initialText;
    private boolean alignLeft = false;

    public MyCustomSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context,@LayoutRes int resource,List<MySpinnerData> spinnerData) 
    {
        super(context, resource,spinnerData);
        spinnerData = spinnerData;
        context = context;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        return myCustomSpinnerView(position, convertView, parent ); 
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        return myCustomSpinnerView(position, convertView, parent);
    }
    private View myCustomSpinnerView(int position, @Nullable View myView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View customview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_layout,parent,false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)customview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(spinnerData.get(position).getIconName());  //function that set text
        return customview;
    }
}
```

This is what i get

[image]


This is custom_spinner.XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"


    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_border"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fontFamily="@font/titillium_web"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:text="simple"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="23dp"
    android:layout_height="23dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/autic" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.00" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />
```

And this is activity_main.XML (spinner)

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Tablice"
    android:layout_width="0dp"


    android:layout_height="89dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"

    android:background="@null"

    android:popupBackground="@color/uplatiParkingDugme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/TablicaDugme"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"

    />
```

Width fullfit great , but as soon as i set match constraint as a width parameter of custom_spinner, a dropdown items wont show?

Can anyone help me? Im stuck on this for a weeks..

Comment: This is a Layout problem and you are posting java code.. Good Work

Comment: @Sam i added XML code, sorry

Comment: all i can see is width `0 dp` everywhere.

Comment: @Sam no need to be rude. If you don't want to help OP then don't comment.

Comment: @ClassA. mentioning their width `0 dp` is being rude? Hmm learned new thing.

Comment: @Sam the way you say it is unnecessary..

Answer (score 0):

After i add

```
customview.measure(0,0);
```

In `MyCustomSpinnerView` method, it works 
But it displays items with low height , not the height of actual spinner?
What does measure function do , and why it works now?